# angular find substring in array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array like this in angular

```
app.myStringArray=
    [   'abcdefg',
        '123456',
        'qwerty'
    ];
```

Currently I have a common method that checks for value being in array like this

```
app.factory('commons', function () {


    var commons= {};

    //Checks if the current url is 
    commons.checkString= function (str) {

        if (app.myStringArray.indexOf(str) > -1) {
            return true; //current string is in list
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return commons;
}
);
```

This works if I send in the full string `'abcdefg'` or `'123456'` or `'qwerty'`.

How can I make it work even if I get part of the string like for eg: `'bcd'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if a string contains another one you can use `String.indexOf()` or as of ES6 `String.includes()`.

To check if at least one item in an array matches a predicate you can use `Array.some()` or simply iterate over the array yourself.

ES6 solution:

```
function checkString(str) {    
  return myStringArray.some(s => s.includes(str));
}
```

ES5 solution:

```
function checkString2(str) {    
  return myStringArray.some(function(s) {
    return s.indexOf(str) > -1;
  });
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be str.indexOf(s) > -1 ?

Comment: @user20358 Not if you want to test if "abcdefg" (=s) contains "bcd" (=str).

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array and check `indexOf(str)` for each string in the array. No need for Angular.

```js
var array = ['abcdefg', '123456', 'qwerty'];

function checkString(str) {
  
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].indexOf(str) > -1) {
      return true;  
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

alert(checkString("bcd"));
```